# "no global superior knowledge" while adding a country

Tags: ldap, openldap, country

I must add an `organizationalunit` like this into a freshly installed OpenLDAP (on Ubuntu 12.04) :

```
dn: ou=MYREGION, ou=MYAPP, ou=GROUPS, o=myorganization, c=fr
ou: MYREGION
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalunit
```

So as it's a new LDAP, I think I must first add the `fr` country, and I create that file :

```
dn: c=fr
c: fr
objectClass: top
objectClass: country
```

Now I try to import it with that command  (I have no domain for that server) :

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,dc=nodomain -W -f country_fr.ldif
```

but OpenLDAP rejects that command with :

```
adding new entry "c=fr"
ldap_add: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
    additional info: no global superior knowledge
```

Any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to [larsks answer](https://serverfault.com/a/469400/93281), here is what I did.

First here is an extract of the default configuration with Ubuntu 12.04 (file `/etc/ldap/slapd.d/cn=config/olcDatabase={1}hdb.ldif`):

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcSuffix: dc=nodomain
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymou
 s auth by dn="cn=admin,dc=nodomain" write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,dc=nodomain" write by * read
olcLastMod: TRUE
olcRootDN: cn=admin,dc=nodomain
```

So I created the following `change_suffix.ldif`:

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: o=myorganization,c=fr
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=admin,o=myorganization,c=fr
-
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by self write by anonymous auth by dn="cn=admin,o=myorganization,c=fr" write by * none
olcAccess: {2}to * by self write by dn="cn=admin,o=myorganization,c=fr" write by * read
```

and added it to my ldap with the following command:

```
sudo ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f change_suffix.ldif
```

Now I had to create the organization node with the following `myorganization.ldif`:

```
dn: o=myorganization,c=fr
objectclass: organization
o: myorganization
```

And finally add it with the following command (the first one didn't work due to `Insufficient access (50)`):

```
ldapadd -x -D cn=admin,o=myorganization,c=fr -W -f myorganization.ldif
```

Now I could add the organizational units:

```
dn: ou=GROUPS, o=myorganization,c=fr
ou: GROUPS
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalunit

dn: ou=MYAPP, ou=GROUPS, o=myorganization,c=fr
ou: MYAPP
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalunit

dn: ou=MYREGION, ou=MYAPP, ou=GROUPS, o=myorganization,c=fr
ou: MYREGION
objectClass: top
objectClass: organizationalunit
```

Comment: This `dn: olcDatabase={1}hdb,cn=config`was key for me, thanks

Answer (score 23):

The error `no global superior knowledge` means that `slapd` doesn't know where to put your new entry.  This typically means that you have not defined an appropriate database.  With newer systems (ones using `cn=config` instead of `slapd.conf`), you would typically first add a new database or modify an existing database entry using `ldapadd` or `ldapmodify`. For example, on my Fedora 17 system, the default install sets up a database like this for hosting `dc=my-domain,dc=com`:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {2}hdb
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
olcDbIndex: objectClass eq,pres
olcDbIndex: ou,cn,mail,surname,givenname eq,pres,sub
structuralObjectClass: olcHdbConfig
creatorsName: cn=config
olcSuffix: dc=my-domain,dc=com
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com
```

To host your organization (`o=myorganization, c=fr`), I would need to create the following LDIF file:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: o=myorganization, c=fr
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,o=myorganization,c=fr
-
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * 
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" write 
  by dn.base="cn=Manager,o=myorganization,c=fr" write
  by * none
```

And I would then load these modifications like this:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f mychanges.ldif
```

This works because of the following `olcAccess` lines already present in the configuration:

```
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
olcDatabase: {0}config
olcAccess: {0}to * 
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" manage
  by * none
```

This grants `root`, contacting `slapd` over the `ldapi:///` socket, password-free access to the `cn=config` tree.

I would then load in my top-level entry:

```
dn: o=myorganization, c=fr
objectclass: organization
o: myorganization
```

By running:

```
ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f myobject.ldif
```

This works because I've added a similar ACL to this database.  Note that I didn't need to start with `c=fr` here, because the database is defined to hold `o=myorganization,c=fr`

Comment: OK, thanks a lot larsks. But if I correctly understand your answer, here you modify the current prefix of the database of this OpenLDAP. What if I would want to add a new one ? (I will test your recommendations anyway, I'm just curious)

Comment: Use `ldapadd` instead of `ldapmodify`, and use the existing record as a model.

Comment: If this answer sovled your problem it would be very kind of you to mark it as accepted by clicking the checkbox to the upper left of the question.

Comment: Actually, it helped me a lot, but it was not the exact commands I passed, that's why I've created my own reply. I didn't dare edit your reply in order to correct it with the ldifs (specially about the `olcAccess`) & commands I really used... but if you want to edit it with copy / paste from my reply, I can mark it acceptable & remove mine :)

Comment: (I think this is not a reason to downvote my answer...)