# Why can't I create my first object in my Open-LDAP server?

Tags: ldap, openldap

I'm trying to set up my first LDAP server that will be used to store user accounts (for things such as mail, git server and a few other things). I managed to install the server, but I'm stuck when I want to create my first object.

The server I want to set up is ashley-vps.mildred.fr (for now, this is a test server). Its dn is `dc=ashley-vps, dc=mildred, dc=fr`. First thing I did was to import the `cosine` (is that a math function?) and `nis` schemas. Then, I modified the `oldSuffix` and `oldRootDN` of my configuration as follows:

```
dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=ashley-vps, dc=mildred, dc=fr
-
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=Manager, dc=ashley-vps, dc=mildred, dc=fr
```

I used the answer at ["no global superior knowledge" while adding a country](https://serverfault.com/questions/469355/no-global-superior-knowledge-while-adding-a-country) as a template.

I don't think I need to set up any special access because I'm using `-Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:///` and when I look at my access settings, I seem to have the necessary permissions:

```
# {0}config, config
dn: olcDatabase={0}config,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth" manage by * none

# {1}monitor, config
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
olcAccess: {0}to * by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external
 ,cn=auth" read by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com" read by * none
```

Now, I'd like to create my first object. Let's start by `dn: dc=ashley-vps, dc=mildred, dc=fr`:

```
dn: dc=ashley-vps, dc=mildred, dc=fr
changetype: add
objectclass: top
objectclass: organizationalUnit
objectclass: dcObject
ou: ashley-vps.mildred.fr
```

I get rejected with:

```
ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
    additional info: no write access to parent
```

I suppose this is because this is beyond the top of the hierarchy managed by the LDAP server, or is it? And if I try to directly create a person:

```
dn: cn=Toto, dc=ashley-vps, dc=mildred, dc=fr
changetype: add
objectclass: person
cn: Toto
sn: Surname
```

I also get rejected with:

```
ldap_add: No such object (32)
```

This time I suppose this is because the top object is missing.

Then, how to create the top object?
Why do I even need to create a top object? This seems like an unnecessary restriction. Similarly, when creating `posixAccount`s, it seems that we also need to create a user and group `organizationalUnit`s (as seen in [this howto](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/archived/LDAP-Implementation-HOWTO/pamnss.html#AEN203)). Can I do without?

Comment: Have you tried it without the spaces?  A lot of LDAP clients (most notably Microsoft ones) don't handle spaces well.

Comment: No, but I'm using `ldapmodify` on Fedora 17 and there are a lot of example that contain spaces. So I'm not too worried about that.

Answer (score 3):

The solution seems to add the `olcAccess` property to `dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config`. I thought I didn't need it, but I do. This makes it possible to modify the database.

So I added the following code to `dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config`:

```
-
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to *
  by dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth" write
  by * none
```

And it now works (at least, I could create `dc=ashley-vps,dc=mildred,dc=fr`)

Note: don't forget to put two space for lines continuations, or else you'll get the following error: [ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80), <olcAccess> handler exited with 1](https://serverfault.com/questions/490638/ldap-modify-other-e-g-implementation-specific-error-80-olcaccess-handl/490639#490639)

edit: see `slapd.access(5)` man page and grant `manage` access to root (the highest permissions)

Answer (score 0):

I realize this is late, but I'll post this for future reference.
The first error I won't address, because I think you simply didn't add a required schema.
But for the error `ldap_add: Insufficient access (50)
    additional info: no write access to parent` 
The following command is used for modifying/adding schema:

```
ldapadd -Q -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -w <password> -f </path/to/file>
```

To add entries to your LDAP use this one instead:

```
ldapadd -x -D 'cn=Manager,dc=domain,dc=local' -w <password> -H ldapi:/// -f </path/to/file>
```