# Error message when setting up OpenLDAP on CentOS

Tags: centos7, openldap

I was adding my domain in the LDAP database and create a file called ldapdomain.ldif for my domain

```
dn: olcDatabase={1}monitor,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to * by 
dn.base="gidNumber=0+uidNumber=0,cn=peercred,cn=external,cn=auth"
  read by dn.base="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" read by * none

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcSuffix
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
replace: olcRootDN
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcRootPW
olcRootPW: {SSHA}PASSWORD

dn: olcDatabase={2}hdb,cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcAccess
olcAccess: {0}to attrs=userPassword,shadowLastChange by
  dn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" write by anonymous auth by self write by * none
olcAccess: {1}to dn.base="" by * read
olcAccess: {2}to * by dn="cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com" write by * read
```

I'm trying to set up OpenLDAP server over CentOS, and I was following this tutorial www.tecmint.com/install-openldap-server-for-centralized-authentication, but I got stuck in the step 10. When I tried to add the ldapdomain.ldif file configuration to the LDAP database, I got an error message saying:

> `ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80) additional info : <olcAccess> handler exited with 1`

Comment: I'm trying to set up OpenLDAP server over CentOS, and I was following this tutorial www.tecmint.com/install-openldap-server-for-centralized-authentication, but I stuck in the step 10, when I tried to add the ldapdomain.ldif file configuration to LDAP database I got an error messege saying <olcAccess> handler existed with 1

Comment: See https://serverfault.com/questions/490638/ldap-modify-other-e-g-implementation-specific-error-80-olcaccess-handl?rq=1 for a possible similar problem

Comment: You have five distinct operations in your LDIF file. Which one fails?

Answer (score 1):

You are setting

```
olcRootDN: cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com
```

There is no access control applied to the *rootdn* anyway.
So you can remove all the  clauses for `cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com`.